# Does a client needs constant access to KMS activation server?

Tags: windows, activation, kms

If we once activate a Windows Server to a KMS server, do we later need connection to that KMS server?

Or is it a completely one-time occasion?

Or at later, when updates come, again connection to KMS server needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows computers attempt to renew KMS activation every seven days. Activation is valid for 180 days.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/volume-activation/activate-windows-10-clients-vamt